# Non zero exit status when installing package

Tags: r

I have been trying to install the baseballr package using the following commands:

```r
if (!requireNamespace('devtools', quietly = TRUE)){ install.packages('devtools') }
devtools::install_github(repo = "BillPetti/baseballr")

# install.packages("devtools") 
devtools::install_github("BillPetti/baseballr", ref = "development_branch")
```

After the code runs, I receive an error message saying that the installation had "non-zero exit status".

Attached is the entire output of the command.

```r
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/pmosb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'baseballr' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.4.11 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'baseballr'
* removing 'C:/Users/pmosb/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/baseballr'
Warning in i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/pmosb/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkNJd0u/file4e3056653a7d/baseballr_1.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

How could I correct this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that `baseballr` required rlang of version 1.0.0 or greater, but you only have version 0.4.11. Try running `install.packages("rlang")` then trying again with `baseballr`.